# Inherit mail.activity on res.partner form

Tags: odoo-13

I cannot find the view which contain Activities on res.partner form view
[image]

I tried to inherit mail.mail_activity_type_view_form but it is not

```
<record id="mail_activity_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mail.activity.type.view.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">mail.activity.type</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mail.mail_activity_type_view_form" />
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML-ID is:

```
mail.res_partner_view_form_inherit_mail
```

So, `mail` addon, `res_partner_view_form_inherit_mail` view.

The view is this one:

```
<record id="res_partner_view_form_inherit_mail" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.partner.view.form.inherit.mail</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='email']" position="replace">
            <field name="is_blacklisted" invisible="1"/>
            <label for="email" class="oe_inline"/>
            <div class="o_row o_row_readonly">
                <i class="fa fa-ban" style="color: red;" role="img" title="This email is blacklisted for mass mailing" aria-label="Blacklisted" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_blacklisted', '=', False)]}" groups="base.group_user"></i>
                <field name="email" widget="email" context="{'gravatar_image': True}" attrs="{'required': [('user_ids','!=', [])]}" />
            </div>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//sheet" position="after">
            <div class="oe_chatter">
                <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
                <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help, you're trying to **`_inherit`** **`mail.activity`** view which is not possible by using **`xml`**, because it will not inherit from xml it is written in **`qweb`**, so for that you have to **`extend`** it like.

```
<t t-extend="idOfMailAvtivityQweb">
    <t t-jquery='i[title="Mark as Todo"]' t-operation="before">
        //Here in thread i will add something before title "Mark as Todo"
    </t>
</t>
```